# Uncaught range error: Invalid string length - Tableau JS API

Tags: javascript, tableau-api

I am trying to pull data and generate a csv using `getUnderlyingDataAsync` method from Tableau JS API.

I want trying to pull in around a million rows (may be more in some cases). But, I see that I am getting an error `Uncaught range error: Invalid string length` when i pass maxRows:200000.

below is relevan part of the code

```
let options = {
  maxRows: 200000,
  includeAllColumns: false
};

let sheet = tableauViz.getWorkbook().getActiveSheet();
sheet.getUnderlyingDataAsync(options).then(function(t) {
 buildCsvData(t);
}, function(err){
 uploadError(err);
});
```

Is this a bug in the API?

Any help in how i can workaround the issue will be really great.